# Unable to call navigator.clipboard.writeText from within Promise

Tags: javascript, html, promise, navigator

I am currently trying to check for read/write clipboard permissions *before* I actually execute `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)` but it doesn't look like the `writeText` is being called. When I try to paste what I just copied, it pastes the previously copied item.

Below is my code.

```
const permissionsCheck = async () => {
    let read = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-read'})
    let write = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write'})
    return write.state === 'granted' && read.state != 'denied'
}

const updateClipboard = (content) => { 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(content).then(() => {
        console.log('Copied links!')
        return true
      /* clipboard successfully set */
    }, () => {
        console.log('Could not copy links!')
        return false
    });
}

const init = async () => {
    await permissionsCheck().then(allowed => {
        if (allowed){
           updateClipboard('Hello world')
        } else {
            alert('NOT ALLOWED')
        }
    })

} 

init()
```

I also tried to write it where `init` wasn't asynchronous, like so.

```
var init = () => {
    permissionsCheck().then(x=>{
        if (allowed){
           updateClipboard('Hello world')
        } else {
            alert('NOT ALLOWED')
        }
    })

}
```

I also tried this syntax.

```
var init = () => {
    const allowed = permissionsCheck()
    if (allowed){
        updateClipboard('Hello world')
    } else {
        alert('NOT ALLOWED')
    }
}
```

The problem with that second and third way I wrote it is that the permissions results were coming back as Promises (as `checkPermissions` is async), so the results were inconsistent. Sometimes the copy would work, other times it would give the alert first and then work on the second or third try.

**Expected Behavior**

`init` waits for the permissions Promise to resolve. Once it's resolved, run `updateClipboard` (if permissions come back positive). It seems like I can't find the happy medium between waiting for the permission results to come back AND executing `writeText` effectively, which is also asynchronous.

I've checked out the Mozilla Docs and scoured Stack but haven't found a use case quite like mine (or I haven't found a clear way to describe what I'm looking for). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the snippet but on Stack Overflow it keeps returning false so I opened a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/VwGMvMo?editors=1010) using the same code where it works better.

```js
const permissionsCheck = async () => {
let read = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-read'})
let write = await navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write'})
return write.state === 'granted' && read.state != 'denied'
}

const updateClipboard = (content) => { 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(content).then(() => {
    console.log('Copied links!')
    return true
  /* clipboard successfully set */
}, () => {
    console.log('Could not copy links!')
    return false
});
}

const init = async () => {
await permissionsCheck().then(allowed => {
    if (allowed){
       updateClipboard('Hello world')
    } else {
        alert('NOT ALLOWED')
    }
})

} 

init()
```

Comment: any chance of a working example where the issue is produced?

Comment: Tried the code and  got a  TypeError: 'clipboard-read' (value of 'name' member of PermissionDescriptor) is not a valid value for enumeration PermissionName. But`clipboard-read`is mentioned on MDN. Looking at articles on MDN revealed inconsistencies that indicate preliminary, incomplete or outdated information in different articles.  The article for `Permissions.query()` provides links to the names different browsers will accept, _which are browser dependent and don't mention the clipboard._ My conclusion is that the Permissions API is not safe to use. Hopefully someone can counter this.

Comment: @damonholden I added a snippet. It keeps returning false in stack overflow for some reason but [this codepen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/VwGMvMo?editors=1010) works better.

Comment: @traktor I am currently only testing it in Chrome, with which the code I provided works but is inconsistent. I think that that the issue is how I'm handling what is essentially a Promise within a Promise.

Comment: you're code seems to work fine in chrome.

Comment: @damonholden I noticed that when I use it onClick (say if I add a button in the HTML that executes `init` then it works. But when I try to run it on it's own using `init()` it doesn't quite work for me. Did you do anything different when you played with the codepen?

Comment: I dont think so, just a copy and paste into vscode and ran a live server. Just posted an answer for some improvements anyway, try and run that code in any contexts with issues and see if it helps. If not i'll modify the asnswer accordingly.

Comment: @damonholden if you try it in the codepen it looks like it throws a DOMException where the document isn't focused. I am working on adding this logic to a chrome extension's content script I am not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: modified the answer to deal with this, seems to work in codepen.

Comment: @damonholden I actually just figured out the focus issue too! I need to simulate/force a focus event. I ended up creating a dummy button to just force a focus before calling `updateClipboard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be much of an issue in you implementation You could be more consistent in the way you write your asynchronous code and how you handle errors in order to prevent and better understand issues in the code:

So a few issues:

- `permissionsCheck` could fail, so I would at least handle this in your `init` function.
- `UpdateClipboard` will never return anything, since your Boolean returns are in the callback functions invoked on promise fulfilment and therefore the overall function will return undefined. I would remove this logic or change to await based logic.
- I would incorporate a `try...catch` at least at top level, to handle any promise rejections in your stack.
- Try to avoid arrow function expressions for declared functions for readability.
- For your issue where the document may not be in focus, add a `document.hasFocus` check.

```
async function permissionsCheck() {
    const read = await navigator.permissions.query({
        name: 'clipboard-read',
    });
    const write = await navigator.permissions.query({
        name: 'clipboard-write',
    });
    return write.state === 'granted' && read.state !== 'denied';
}

async function updateClipboard(content) {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(content);
    console.log('Copied links!');
}

async function init() {
    try {
        const hasPermissions = await permissionsCheck();

        if (hasPermissions && document.hasFocus()) {
            updateClipboard('Hello world');
        } else {
            alert('NOT ALLOWED');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

init();
```

Here, if any part of this call stack throws, `init` will catch and log it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried implementing your code in the codepen but have gotten the `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.` error. I've gotten it before but for some reason I am now getting it even when the console is closed and I trigger an alert to focus the DOM.

Comment: For some reason I was unable to get the document to be focused so I was able to create a button, focus it, call `updateClipboard` then remove the button from the DOM. It appears pretty consistent now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, hope what your building turns out well.